# sorted map in ACL2

Tags: indexing, acl2

I have to use a *sorted* map/index structure in ACL2. Currently I have the following:

```
( (key1 . (val1 val2)) (key2 . (val3)) (key3 . (val4 val5 val6)) )
```

Is there any other way of doing this more efficiently?

Comment: Possibly using a tree structure?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me, from your example, what you are trying to do.

You could certainly define operations on an association list that keep it in a key-sorted order.  In that case:

- your `get` function would look just like acons
- your `put` function would need to look for the "right" place to put the element.

But this isn't particularly efficient.  Both operations would be O(n).  Also, as a practical consideration, the `put` operation would require O(n) conses, which is especially expensive since `cons` allocates memory.

Usually it's better to just use ordinary association lists, i.e., using `acons` and `assoc`.   The main advantage is that, since it simply conses the new key/value pair onto the front of the list, `acons` is O(1), so constructing your mappings is generally much cheaper.  You can always sort the keys of the alist if you need to, e.g., using [set::mergesort](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/?topic=SET____MERGESORT) or some custom sorting function.

Accessing alists is still O(n).  However, [fast-alists](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/?topic=ACL2____FAST-ALISTS) are available in ACL2(h) and essentially provide a way to get alists with hash table speeds.  See also the documentation for [std/alists](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/?topic=ACL2____STD_F2ALISTS).